# Macro argument not being substituted in

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl, parenscript

I'm trying to fully understand the limitations of compile-time macros.

Here is a macro (I'm fully aware that this is not a *best-practice* macro):

```lisp
(defmacro emit (language file &body body)
  (print language)
  (print file)
  (print body)
  (with-open-file (str file :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
    (princ (cond ((eq language 'html)
                  (cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (s nil :prologue t :indent t) body))
                 ((eq language 'javascript)
                  (parenscript:ps body))
                 ((eq language 'json)
                  (remove #\; (parenscript:ps body))))
           str)))
```

I compile the macro:

```
; processing (DEFMACRO EMIT ...)
PROGRAM>
```

I compile this form:

```
PROGRAM> (compile nil (lambda () (emit json "~/file" (ps:create "hi" "hello") (ps:create "yo" "howdy"))))

JSON 
"~/file" 
((PARENSCRIPT:CREATE "hi" "hello") (PARENSCRIPT:CREATE "yo" "howdy")) 
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {5367482B}>
NIL
NIL
PROGRAM>
```

The compile-time `print` output is what I expect.

However, if I look at `~/file`:

```
body
```

It appears that `((PARENSCRIPT:CREATE "hi" "hello") (PARENSCRIPT:CREATE "yo" "howdy"))` was never substituted in for the parameter `body`, and thus never processed.

Why is this?

& what would be the best literature to read on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should it substitute?  You never substituted anything.

A macro defines a macro substitution function, which is applied to the actual form in the code to produce another form which is then compiled.  When you apply your macro definition to those parameters, it will *at macroexpansion time* do all kinds of things (write a file etc.) before returning what `princ` returned, which is exactly its first argument, and this returned form is then compiled.  I don't think that is what you want.

It seems that what you actually want to do is to expand to a form that interprets the body in one of a variety of ways, indicated by the first argument.

What you need to do is to return the new form, so that

```lisp
(emit 'html "foo.html"
  (:html (:head) (:body "whatever")))
```

expands to

```lisp
(with-open-file (str "foo.html" :direction :output :etc :etc)
  (cl-who:with-html-output (str)
    (:html (:head) (:body "whatever")))
```

For that, we have a template syntax: the backtick.

```lisp
`(foo ,bar baz)
```

means the same as

```lisp
(list 'foo bar 'baz)
```

but makes the structure of transformed code a bit clearer.  There is also `,@` to *splice* things into a list.

```lisp
`(foo ,@bar)
```

means the same as

```lisp
(list* 'foo bar)
```

i. e. the contents of `bar`, when they are a list, are spliced into the list.  This is especially useful for bodies such as in your macro.

```lisp
(defmacro emit (language file &body body)
  `(with-open-file (str ,file :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
     (princ (cond ((eq ,language 'html)
                   (cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (s nil :prologue t :indent t)
                     ,@body))
                  ((eq ,language 'javascript)
                   (parenscript:ps ,@body))
                  ((eq ,language 'json)
                   (remove #\; (parenscript:ps ,@body))))
            str)))
```

Note where I introduced the backtick to create a template and commata to put outer arguments into it.  Note also that the arguments are *forms*.

This has a few problems: there are hardcoded symbols that the user of the macro has no way of knowing.  In one case (`str`) they have to pay attention not to shadow it, in the other (`s`) they have to know it in order to write to it.  For this, we use either generated symbols (for `str` so that there is no conflict possible) or let the user say what they want to name it (for `s`).  Also, this `cond` can be simplified to a `case`:

```lisp
(defmacro emit (language file var &body body)
  (let ((str (gensym "str")))
    `(with-open-file (,str ,file
                      :direction :output
                      :if-exists :supersede)
       (princ (case ,language
                ('html
                 (cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (,var nil
                                                     :prologue t
                                                     :indent t)
                   ,@body))
                ('javascript
                 (parenscript:ps ,@body))
                ('json
                 (remove #\; (parenscript:ps ,@body))))
              ,str)))
```

However, you might want to determine the output code already at macro expansion time.

```lisp
(defmacro emit (language file var &body body)
  (let ((str (gensym "str")))
    `(with-open-file (,str ,file
                      :direction :output
                      :if-exists :supersede)
       (princ ,(case language
                 ('html
                  `(cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (,var nil
                                                       :prologue t
                                                       :indent t)
                     ,@body))
                 ('javascript
                  `(parenscript:ps ,@body))
                 ('json
                  `(remove #\; (parenscript:ps ,@body))))
              ,str)))
```

Here, you can see that the `case` form is already evaluated at macro expansion time, and an inner template is then used to create the inner form.

This is all completely untested, so removing the little errors is left as an exercise ^^.

One book that has a lot of things to say about macro writing is »On Lisp« by Paul Graham.  The freely available »Practical Common Lisp« by Peter Seibel also has a chapter about it, and there are also some recipes in »Common Lisp Recipes« by Edi Weitz.

Answer (score 1):

`parenscript:ps` is a macro, not a function: its body is literal parenscript and is not evaluated but compiled, from Parenscript to JavaSctipt.  This is easy to check:

```
> (parenscript:ps body)
"body;"
```

I don't have any advice on what you should read: this macro looks so utterly confused I can't really understand what the underlying intent was.  A macro in CL is a function which whose argument is source code in some language L1 and which returns source code in some language L2, where L2 is usually a subset of L1.  I can't work out, though, if this is just the normal case of someone thinking they need a macro when they need a function, or if it's some other confusion.